# Why apache does not update media files when I update tham in my FileSystem?

Tags: php, apache, flash, xampp, media

Why Apache does not update media files when I update them in my file system? (I use xampp on Windows to manage Apache) So when I update my php files I see changes immediately byt when I update media files like .swf's it does note update them when I call them. Why, and how to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a issue of the browser cache and not of Apache web server.
See [php header function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). There is a section about caching. You also could use a .htaccess file for cache controll.

Answer (score 1):

They probably are in the browser's cache. Clean the browser's cache, or reload using SHIFT+F5 (it usually works), or serve the media files through a PHP file which instructs the files not to be cached.